# Add 'banner" with date/time to files optimized by RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

In grunt, you can add a "banner" to files that have been concatenated and minfied like so:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
      add_banner: {
        options: {
          banner: '/* My minified css file */'
        },
        files: {
          'dist/css/dist.min.css': ["bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css", "tmp/css/dist.css"]
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing with RequireJS? I'ved looked in the [example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) provided in the [RequireJS documentation](http://www.requirejs.org), but have not been able to find any such option.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `wrap` option of the r.js configuration:

```
({
    ...
    "wrap": {
        "start": "/* My minified css file */\n",
        "end": ""
    },
    ...
})
```